# Phonegap landscape orientation [samsung tab 3]

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova, cordova-3

Hey guys i have already done the research and have searched before posting this question i am unable get the app to lock in landscape mode here is my config.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.gemin.resort" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>demoapp</name>
    <description>
        This is demo app
    </description>
    <author email="demo@test.com" href="http://www.demo.com">
       demo user
    </author>

    <!--
        Enable individual API permissions here.
        The "device" permission is required for the 'deviceready' event.
    -->
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <preference name="phonegap-version"      value="3.4.0" />       <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" /> 
    <preference name="orientation"                value="landscape" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
              <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="6" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->

    <!-- Plugins can also be added here. -->
    <!--
        <gap:plugin name="Example" />
        A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins
    -->

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"         gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />

    <!--
        Define access to external domains.

        <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
        <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

        Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
    -->
    <access origin="*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
    <!--
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->

</widget>
```

and my androidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.gemin.resort" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="HelloWorld" android:screenOrientation="userLandscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

I have found the problem its this line in androidmanifest.xml

**android:screenOrientation="userLandscape"** this has to be  **android:screenOrientation="Landscape"**

even if i manually change this in manifest.xml during compilation from CLI it changes back to userLandscape kindly help

Comment: Are you changing the AndroidManifest in your bin/ folder and then recompiling...?

Comment: tried it but no use, my apk is stored at ant-build tried changing the manifest in ant-build and same problem

Answer (score 1):

```
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

> Add this line in your android manifest in  tag. This will solve your problem.

Comment: its already there android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"

Comment: what the exact issue is ? can u plz explain ...it is an orientation problem or something else ?

Comment: when i compile the phonegap app my manifest is overwritten by the compiler

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in 3.4.0: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6312

I'd say these are your options:

1. Remove the preference and just manually add it to the AndroidManifest

   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
2. Update Phonegap to 3.5.0
3. Use a plugin instead: https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock